# Keras AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Tags: python, keras

Im attempting to find model performance metrics (F1 score, accuracy, recall) following this guide https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-calculate-precision-recall-f1-and-more-for-deep-learning-models/

This exact code was working a few months ago but now returning all sorts of errors, very confusing since i havent changed one character of this code. Maybe a package update has changed things?

I fit the sequential model with model.fit, then used model.evaluate to find test accuracy. Now i am attempting to use model.predict_classes to make class predictions (model is a multi-class classifier). Code shown below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

-

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 256, epochs = 10, verbose = 2, validation_split = 0.2)

-

score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,verbose=2, batch_size= 256)
print('test accuracy:', acc)

-

yhat_classes = model.predict_classes(X_test)
```

last line returns error "AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'"

This exact code was working not long ago so struggling a bit, thanks for any help

Comment: are you running this on colab?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This function was removed in TensorFlow version 2.6.
According to the [keras in rstudio reference](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/reference/keras/predict_proba.html#usage)

update to

```py
predict_x=model.predict(X_test) 
classes_x=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1)
```

**Or use TensorFlow 2.5.x .**

If you are using TensorFlow version 2.5, you will receive the following warning:

> tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py:455: UserWarning: `model.predict_classes()` is deprecated and will be removed after 2021-01-01. Please use instead:* `np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)`,   if your model does multi-class classification   (e.g. if it uses a `softmax` last-layer activation).* `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`,   if your model does binary classification   (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer activation).

Comment: The link is now broken.

Comment: The broken link has been fixed.

Answer (score 43):

I experienced the same error, I use this following code, and succeed

Replaced:

```
predictions = model.predict_classes(x_test)
```

With this one:

```
predictions = (model.predict(x_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")
```

Type of python packages : Tensorflow 2.6.0

Comment: Thanks replacing it with your suggested code worked!

Comment: Thanks. Code Worked for me. I was using Keras.

Answer (score 12):

In the newest version of Tensorflow, the `predict_classes` function has been deprecated (there was a warning in previous versions about this).  The new syntax is as follows:

```
predictions = np.argmax(model.predict(x_test),axis=1)
```

Comment: use code block for your code when typing

Comment: Any links to the documentation?

Comment: Worked better than previous answers

Answer (score 10):

We can replace the problematic code line with the following:

```py
y_predict = np.argmax(model.predict(x_test), axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 9):

I used following code for predictions

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.round(y_pred).astype(int)
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The previous answer did.

Answer (score 6):

In Tensorflow 2.7 predicted classes can be obtained with the following code:

```
    predicted = np.argmax(model.predict(token_list),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this code below for an entire dataset,

```
preds = model.predict_classes(test_sequences)
```

This code can be used for the new versions.

```
y_predict = np.argmax(model.predict(test_sequences), axis=1)
```

In this, the "*test_sequence*" is the data frame u have to predict, and the *axis* is to choose either columns or rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as the predict_classes are removed with the latest version of tensorflow

```
predictions = (model.predict(X_test) > 0.5)*1
```

Since this is a binary problem (0 or 1), the output class is determined by whether the probability is bigger than 0.5. Hence the code above

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a multi-class classification then use
`np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)`

for example :

```
predictions = np.argmax(model.predict(x_test),axis=1)
```

Or else if you have a Binary classification problem at hand use `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`

for example :

```
`predictions=(model.predict(X_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")`
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this and worked:

```
y_pred_prob = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.round(y_pred_prob)
```