# LSTM RNN 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm running predictions on an RNN model and it errors saying:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-cd3fe876f68d> in <module>
      1 # Make sentiment predictions
----> 2 predictions = model.predict_classes(X_test)

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
```

I'm doing a complicated sentiment analysis model that feeds encoded/tokens comments into a Deep NN work using LSTM Layers, the goal is can a RNN be fed all these comments and predict the positivity score of the each comment in this .csv file of 25,000 comments. The model will output either 0 for negative comment or 1 for positive comment.

So I'm at the final stages. I pre-processed and encoded/tokenized all my data, built the NN model, and now I'm running it to train. I decided to train on a few epochs because it's eating the memory of laptop.

```
# Training the model
batch_size = 1000
epochs = 10

model.fit(
    X_train_rnn,
    y_train_rnn,
    validation_data = (X_val_rnn, y_val_rnn),
    epochs = epochs,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    verbose = 1
)
```

After my computer trains this model for minutes on end, then I try to make predictions and this where I get the error:

```
y_rnn_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test_rnn, batch_size=1000)
```

Comment: [Looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68841446/18313927) the function was deprecated in TF 2.5

Comment: what is your tensorflow.version? Do you try `model.predict()?`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tf.keras version 2.5+
replace

```
y_rnn_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test_rnn, batch_size=1000)
```

with

```
y_rnn_pred = (model.predict(X_test_rnn, batch_size=1000) > 0.5).astype("int32")
```