# How do I fix an 'AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes' in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, attributeerror

I am running a program from a public colab for MNIST using keras library. I am unable to run this block of code. I attempted to import the new keras attributes, and updating TensorFlow. However I still run into the no 'predict
_classes' Attribute error.

Does anyone have a fix to this?

```
import numpy as np                   # advanced math library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt      # MATLAB like plotting routines
import random                        # for generating random numbers
import tensorflow as keras

from keras.datasets import mnist     # MNIST dataset is included in Keras
from keras.models import Sequential  # Model type to be used

from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation # Types of layers to be used in our model
from keras.utils import np_utils                         # NumPy related tools

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

```
# The predict_classes function outputs the highest probability class
# according to the trained classifier for each input example.


predicted_classes = model.predict_classes(X_test)
predict_x = model.predict(X_test) 
classes_x=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1)


# Check which items we got right / wrong
correct_indices = np.nonzero(predicted_classes == y_test)[0]

incorrect_indices = np.nonzero(predicted_classes != y_test)[0]
```

I also attempted to use the suggestions from this Stack Overflow however I was unable to get them to work. I took them out in this posting.

[Keras AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836551/keras-attributeerror-sequential-object-has-no-attribute-predict-classes)

Comment: How do you get object 'model'? I don't see it in your code above. Indeed keras.models.Sequential does not have predicted_classes. This line also does not make much sense, since predicted classes in your case are next two lines - get model output (class probabilities) and obtain predicted classes from it (argmax)

Answer (score 0):

As the people said already in the link you posted, **predict_classes()** was deprecated (not exist anymore) so you can not use it. Instead, you can use **predict()** which returns you the probabilities (in range of 0-1, dependent on your loss function of course) then you can get the classes by applying a threshold like 0.5 in case of sigmoid, or get the maximum probability in case of softmax (as you did in your code with np.argmax).