# plotting the distribution of classes in an image data while using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory but not able to obtain the labels array

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, visualization

I have loaded the data using **tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory** but in order to plot the distribution of classes in the dataset I need to obtain the classes array. It seems that the dataset returned by the method does not offer any way to obtain the same. If anyone have resolved this or has any idea on how to do the same kindly share the ideas.

the data is arranged in a folder structure to identify classes.

```
  train_ds= tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(224, 224),
  labels='inferred',
  label_mode='categorical',
  batch_size=15
  )
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687375/get-labels-from-dataset-when-using-tensorflow-image-dataset-from-directory

Answer (score 0):

From the answers at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64687375/14774959), you could iterate over your `tf.data.Dataset` to obtain the list of all labels:

```
labels =  np.array([])
for x, y in testData:
  # this if your labels are one-hot encoded
  labels = np.concatenate([labels, np.argmax(y.numpy(), axis=-1)])
  # this if they aren't
  labels = np.concatenate([labels, y])
```

Then to get your classes list you could convert the list of labels into a set. The set contains only unique occurrences by definition:

```
classes = set(labels)
print(classes)
```